# How to save mysql search result in variable

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am trying to use the variable i got from MySQL via PHP in JavaScript. I am guessing the problem lies in this line: `$speicher = $row['Vorname']`

How can I use a regular PHP variable in order to store my search result and reuse it in javaScript?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org

/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Seite1</title>
<meta name="author" content="admin1212">
<meta name="editor" content="html-editor phase 5">
</head>
<body text="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" link="#FF0000" alink="#FF0000" vlink="#FF0000">
<img src="http://lodsb.org/socialcomp/artemis/1405.jpg" onload= "tim()">
<input  type="button" value=" TAG1" id=" TAG1" name="select" style="height: 25px; width: 100px" size="100" onclick= "sel2(this)">
<input  type="button" value=" TAG2" id=" TAG2" name="select" style="height: 25px; width: 100px" size="100" onclick= "sel2(this)">
<input  type="button" value=" TAG3" id=" TAG3" name="select" style="height: 25px; width: 100px" size="100" onclick= "sel2(this)">
<input  type="button" value=" TAG4" id=" TAG4" name="select" style="height: 25px; width: 100px" size="100" onclick= "sel2(this)">
<input  type="button" value=" TAG5" id=" TAG5" name="select" style="height: 25px; width: 100px" size="100" onclick= "sel2(this)">
<input  type="button" value=" TAG6" id=" TAG6" name="select" style="height: 25px; width: 100px" size="100" onclick= "sel2(this)">


<input type = "text" id = "count" readonly="readonly" value="0" >
<input type = "text" id = "sel1" readonly="readonly" value="" >
<input type = "text" id = "sel2" readonly="readonly" value="" >

<?php   

    $speicher = "Hallo";



    // mit dem Datenbankserver verbinden
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error());

    // Datenbank auswählen
    mysql_select_db("Menschen") or die(mysql_error());

    // SQL-Query
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Personen";

    // Query ausführen (die Datensatzgruppe $rs enthält das Ergebnis)
    $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

    // Schleifendurchlauf durch $rs
    // Jede Zeile wird zu einem Array ($row), mit mysql_fetch_array
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
      $speicher = $row['Vorname']
       // Schreibe den Wert der Spalte Vorname (der jetzt im Array $row ist)
      echo $row['Vorname'] . "<br />";



      }




    // Schließt die Datenbankverbindung
    mysql_close();


    echo "Success: ";
    echo date("r");





    ?>

<input  type="button" value="FUNKTION" id="button7" name="noselect" style="height: 25px; width: 100px" size="100" onclick= "a()">


</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Mauskontrolle (Element) {
  Element.value="777777777"
}

function sel2 (Button){
var counter = document.getElementById("count").value
var sel1 = document.getElementById("sel1")
var sel2 = document.getElementById("sel2")


if (counter==0){
sel1.value = Button.id
}
if (counter==1){
if (sel1.value == Button.id){ return }
sel2.value = Button.id
}
counter++
if (counter >=2){
counter=0
alert(sel1.value + " " + sel2.value)

}

document.getElementById("count").value  = counter

}
function emp(){
var arr = document.getElementsByName("select")
//alert(arr.length)
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
arr[i].value=""
}
}
function tim(){
window.setTimeout(emp, 5000)
}
function a(){
var Ergebnis = '<?php echo $speicher;?>';
alert(Ergebnis);
}



</script>
```

Comment: The code looks okay .. do you get an error or something?

Comment: Note that your javascript is out of the HTML tags.

Comment: @explosion pills:yeah actually i get an error:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Seite2.php on line 47

Comment: @Luigi siri: does that really make any diffrence? so far i was able to call the javascript functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a more complex question for a beginner, but normally you could use PHP to echo javascript, so you could possibly take your results array, loop through and echo out javascript ... here is a brief example to get you started.

```
echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>var resultsArr = new Array();</script>";


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

      $speicher = $row['Vorname'];

      echo $row['Vorname'] . "<br />";

      echo "<script type='text/javascript'> resultsArr['Vorname'] = \"".$row['Vorname']."\" </script>";


}
```

Comment: Hi, i think i get what you mean, quite sharp to hardcode it in the website ;) Just for the sake of completeness i added a $counter =0; outside the while statment and increased it when the loop is executed and changed your script to: echo "<script type='text/javascript'> resultsArr[$coutner] = ...                  with this i can get access to ALL search results in my javascript just by using: resultsArr[INDEX]  Thanks a lot :D !!!

Answer (score 1):

Just echo it in as the value of the javascript var

```
var yourjavascriptvar = <?php echo $row['Vorname']; ?>;
```

Comment: The OP does that, almost at the end of the code. --var Ergebnis = '<?php echo $speicher;?>';

Comment: Thats unfortunately not working. If I display the content of the var with alert it shows nothing...

Answer (score 0):

You forget the semicolon

```
  $speicher = $row['Vorname'];
```

Comment: You are right, that was indeed the problem, works fine now but contains only the last search result, as expected. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how php works. PHP pre-process page executing functions. When you use function "echo" it adds content to your webpage, which is send to browser and then executes javascript code.

In order to use values in javascript you need to echo them in php, like there where always there.

```
var jsValueName = '<?php echo $row["columnName"]; ?>';
```

Remember about enclosing with: ' '

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advise but thats not working, probably because $row[] is not visible outside the while statement. ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are somethings that might be wrong in this code...

**First**: A line in your code is missing a semicolon.

```
 $speicher = $row['Vorname']
```

**Second**: You are fetching your result (**s**) to one variable, $speicher.

**Third**: Your javascript is out of the HTML tags. It might don't work, but if it does is not a proper way to do it.

**Fourth**: The way you are using the PHP variable to use it in javascript seems good to me.

```
 var Ergebnis = '<?php echo $speicher;?>';
```